# Are there any Vaishnava commentaries on Vedas available?

Tags: vedas, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, gaudiya-vaishnavism, dvaita

I am looking for english translation of Vaishnava commentaries on Vedas (Samhita) if any are available. Any sampradaya be it Sri Vaishnava or Madhavaite or Gaudiya or any other is ok. In general,I want to know how Vaishnavas sees Vedic verses specifically Rig Veda and others.

Comment: There are commentaries on the Upanishads by Madhva here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda actually I am looking for commentary on Vedic Samhita. I know commentary on Upanishads are available since they are part of Prasthantrayi. I think I should have been more specific in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can download PDF of Madhvācārya's commentary on Ṛgveda http://www.tatvavada.org/eng/works/pdf/rgb.pdf

Comment: Namaste Welcome to HSE! You can have a look the help centre on answering questions as well as [guidelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Your answer is okay but since you’re new it’s advisable to give you the link to these things